# How to find the roots of a function whose analytical form is not known, rather the function is available as a tabulated set of values?

Tags: c, algorithm, function

To find the roots of a function, we can generally use bisection method or Newton's method. For  a function f(x), this is possible only when we have an analytical expression for the x-dependence of f(x).

I am trying to find the roots of such a function where I don't know the exact form of the function, rather I have a tabulated data for the values of f(x) for each values of x in a particular range of x. I am writing my program in C and I am using a for-loop to calculate f(x) for each value of x by solving a non-linear equation using bisection method and tabulating the data. Now I need to find the roots of the function f(x).

Can anyone help me with any suitable method or algorithm for the problem?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `for each values of x` Is `x` discreet? `calculate f(x) for each value of x` what for, you just stated that you already _have a tabulated data for the values of f(x) for each values of x_. So if you have them, just find rows where `x = 0`.

Comment: You are somehow guessing or approximating `f(x)` by constructing a function `g(x)` which gives the same results `f(x[i])=g(x[i])` for a given set of `{x[1],x[2],...}` where `f(x[i])` is known from your table. In my opinion, the best you can do is to find the roots of `g(x)` and hope that `f(x)` has similar roots. But without knowing more about `f(x)`, that is strictly guesswork.

Comment: If you *can't* calculate f(x) for every x, but you only have some tabulated values for some  x, you could perform a binary search to find the two values such that, say f(x_a) <0 and f(x_b) >0, and then use some interpolation to better estimate x in that range. If you *can*, somehow, evaluate f(x) for every x, but it's just time consuming, you still can use a method like bisection  or any other which approximates the derivates of the function.

Comment: Yes, I can calculate f(x) for each value of x by solving another non-linear equation. For example, in bisection method, two values of x (a and b)  are required and then the root is calculated by checking whether the condition f(a)*f(b)<0. I am also trying to apply the same approach. The only difference being that rather calculating f(a) and f(b) in the loop for bisection method, I am trying to import the values of f(a) and f(b) from a text file.

Comment: Do I understand right that the values `y=f(x)` are obtained by solving some equation `0=g(x,y)` for fixed `x`? Then the roots could also be found by directly solving the scalar equation `0=g(x,0)`.

Answer (score 2):

You know from where the sign changes that a root has to be between two points.

Take several nearby points, put a polynomial through them, and then solve for the root of that polynomial using Newton's method.

From your description it looks like you should be able to calculate your function at this new point.  If so, then I would suggest that you calculate the value at this point, add the two nearest neighbors, calculate a parabola and solve for the root of that.  If your function is smooth and has a non-zero derivative at the root, this step will make your estimate of the root several orders of magnitude more accurate.

(You can repeat again for even more accuracy.  But the increased accuracy at this point may be on par with the numerical errors in your estimate of the value of the function.)